# Mounting external HD 4 TB failed with error message (ubuntu 16.04.2)

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

Mounting external HD Seagate 4 TB in Kubuntu failed with error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/fritz/Seagate Backup Plus Drive: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda1" "/media/fritz/Seagate Backup Plus Drive"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

However, mounting with Windows 8.1 was OK.

How can I mount with kubuntu again ?

Comment: Did you eject properly the HD the last time you used it on Windows ?

Comment: Probably still hibernated. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation, But some large NTFS drives are formatted/partitioned with proprietary configurations to make them compatible with XP. Check if drive shown as gpt which it must be not MSDOS/DOS/MBR which then is not compatible as the full 4TB.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Windows.

First we check/fix the disk structure, then we turn off `fast start` and `hibernation`.

- in an administrative command prompt window, type `chkdsk /f D:` and change the D to the appropriate drive letter
- open power control panel, choose `Change what power buttons do`, then choose `Change options that are unavailable`, then uncheck `Fast Start`
- in an administrative command prompt window, type `powercfg /h off`

Then reboot into kubuntu and all should be well.